# Deleting a jar from another jar

Tags: java, jar

I have two jar files, `Foo.jar` and `Bar.jar`. Inside `Foo.jar` I have a class `Foo` with a `main` method which looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.sayHello();
    new File("./Bar.jar").deleteOnExit();
  }
}
```

The class `Bar` lives in `Bar.jar` and looks like this:

```
public class Bar {
  public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello! I'm Bar!");
  }
}
```

The intention here is that `Foo.jar` will use a class in `Bar.jar` and afterwards it will delete `Bar.jar`. With the above implementation this is the output when executed:

```
$ java -jar Foo.jar
Hello! I'm Bar!
```

but `Bar.jar` does not get deleted. Here I've tried both `new File("./Bar.jar").deleteOnExit();` and `new File("./Bar.jar").delete();` in class `Foo`.

If I change class `Bar` to close its ClassLoader like this:

```
public class Bar {
  public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello! I'm Bar!");

    URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    try {
      classLoader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

and run `Foo.jar` again, this is the output:

```
$ java -jar Foo.jar
Hello! I'm Bar!
```

the output is the same as in the previous example, but in this case `Bar.jar` is deleted, which is great, but the problem now is that if I do something like this in class `Foo`:

```
9   public class Foo {
10    public static void main(String[] args) {
11      Bar bar = new Bar();
12      bar.sayHello();
13    
14      new File("./Bar.jar").deleteOnExit();
15    
16      SimpleFileVisitor<Path> visitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
17      };
18    }
19  }
```

this becomes the output of executing `Foo.jar`:

```
$ java -jar Foo.jar
Hello! I'm Bar!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: playground/modulae/Foo$1
        at playground.modulae.Foo.main(Foo.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: playground.modulae.Foo$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

In this case, `Bar.jar` still gets deleted, but when I try to create a new `SimpleFileVisitor` it crashes with a `NoClassDefFoundError`. It seems like closing the ClassLoader in `Bar.jar` causes things to get a bit messed up for `Foo.jar` as well, but I have not found any other way that lets me delete `Bar.jar` from `Foo.jar`.

The general structure of this example closely resembles what happens in the real application, which uses `java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor` later on. I've tried creating a few other classes instead of `java.no.file.SimpleFileVisitor` and none of them crash, but I guess it depends on whether or not they have been loaded by the ClassLoader before `Foo` calls `Bar`.

---

### Update

After messing around with class loaders (which I still don't fully understand) I have something that seems to be sufficient. However, I fear that I'm doing something a bit dodgy and that there is a more 'correct' way of handling the class loader manipulation that I'm doing.

So the setup now is:

1. I have class `Foo` with a `main` method and a `speak()` method in `Foo.jar`.
2. A class `Bar` with a simple `sayHello()` method in `Bar.jar`.
3. In the `main` function I create an instance `foo` of `Foo` with a custom class loader and call `foo.speak()`
4. In `foo.speak()` I create a instance `bar` of `Bar` like this: `Bar bar = new Bar()` <- Notice that there is no reflection or anything fancy here. Then I call `bar.sayHello()`
5. In `bar.sayHello()` I call`this.getClass().getClassLoader().close()`
6. Everything then returns to `main` which deletes `Bar.jar`

And then the code:

#### Foo.java (in Foo.jar)

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    System.out.println("Foo.main: Class path: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

    URLClassLoader initialClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) Foo.class.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("Foo.main: initialClassLoader = " + initialClassLoader);
    System.out.println("Foo.main: initialClassLoader.getURLs() = " + Arrays.toString(initialClassLoader.getURLs()));

    File fooJar = new File("./Foo.jar");
    File barJar = new File("./Bar.jar");

    CustomClassLoader customClassLoader = new CustomClassLoader(new URL[]{fooJar.toURI().toURL(), barJar.toURI().toURL()});
    System.out.println("Foo.main: customClassLoader = " + customClassLoader);
    System.out.println("Foo.main: customClassLoader.getURLs() = " + Arrays.toString(customClassLoader.getURLs()));
    Class<?> fooClass = customClassLoader.findClass("Foo");
    Object foo = fooClass.newInstance();
    Method speak = fooClass.getMethod("speak");
    speak.invoke(foo);

    barJar.deleteOnExit();

    SimpleFileVisitor<Path> visitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    };
  }

  public void speak() {
    System.out.println("Foo.speak()");
    URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("Foo.speak(): classLoader = " + classLoader);
    System.out.println("Foo.speak(): classLoader.getURLs() = " + Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.sayHello();
  }
}
```

#### Bar.java (in Bar.jar)

```
public class Bar {
  public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Bar.sayHello()");
    URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("Bar.sayHello(): classLoader = " + classLoader);
    System.out.println("Bar.sayHello(): classLoader.getURLs() = " + Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));

    try {
      classLoader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

#### CustomClassLoader (in Foo.jar)

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {      
  public CustomClassLoader(URL[] urls) {
    super(urls);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return super.findClass(name);
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
$ java -jar Foo.jar
Foo.main: Class path: Foo.jar
Foo.main: initialClassLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1f96302
Foo.main: initialClassLoader.getURLs() = [file:/Foo.jar]
Foo.main: customClassLoader = CustomClassLoader@a298b7
Foo.main: customClassLoader.getURLs() = [file:/Foo.jar, file:/Bar.jar]
Foo.speak()
Foo.speak(): classLoader = CustomClassLoader@a298b7
Foo.speak(): classLoader.getURLs() = [file:/Foo.jar, file:/Bar.jar]
Bar.sayHello()
Bar.sayHello(): classLoader = CustomClassLoader@a298b7
Bar.sayHello(): classLoader.getURLs() = [file:/Foo.jar, file:/Bar.jar]
```

and `Bar.jar` is deleted.

#### Thoughts

As we see, `Bar` can be referenced from within `Foo.jar` without any reflection, it has been loaded with the correct `CustomClassLoader` and `Bar.jar` can successfully be deleted from `Foo` after having called `bar.sayHello()`.

Now, this solves my problem. However, I'm not confident that I have solved the `CustomClassLoader` correctly. In fact, the only thing that `CustomClassLoader` effectively does is make `findClass()` public. I tried a whole bunch of different ways of implementing `loadClass()`, but could never get it to work and just by accident I tried `findClass()` instead and it worked.

Does anyone have any opinions on how `CustomClassLoader` is used?

Comment: Is your file playground/modulae/Foo$1.class in Foo.jar or in Bar.jar?

Comment: I'm guessing it is referring to the anonymous `SimpleFileVisitor` class created on line 16. If line 16 is removed, then things work as expected; `Bar.jar` get's deleted and the program doesn't crash. Adding line 16 leads to the crash shown in the question.
But to answer your question directly: It is in `Foo.jar`

Comment: You closed the system class loader of your thread. So any subsequent class loading will fail...

Comment: I figured it had to be something like that, but as I said; it was the only way I found that made is possible to delete `Bar.jar` from `Foo.jar`. Do you have any input as to how I can achieve that, without closing the class loader in `Bar.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here what I would do:

I would define an interface to use by `Foo`, and implement by `Bar`:

```
public interface BarIntf {
    public void sayHello();
}
```

The interface must be in Foo.jar.

The `Bar` class would implement `BarIntf`:

```
public class Bar implements BarIntf {
    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello! I'm Bar!");
    }
}
```

Now, instead of putting both Foo.jar and Bar.jar in the classpath, I would put only Foo.jar, and create a class loader in program `Foo` just to load the `Bar` class.

It looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File jar = new File("./Bar.jar");
        try (URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[] {jar.toURI().toURL()})) {
            Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("bar.Bar");
            BarIntf bar = (BarIntf)clazz.newInstance();
            bar.sayHello();
            // ...a lot of very useful things
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException
                | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            jar.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

With reflection (no interface required):

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File jar = new File("./Bar.jar");
        try (URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[] {jar.toURI().toURL()})) {
            Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("bar.Bar");
            Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("sayHello");
            Object bar = clazz.newInstance();
            method.invoke(bar);
            // ...a lot of very useful things
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException
                | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
                | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            jar.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, although not applicable in my situation. `Bar.jar` cannot have any references to `Foo.jar`

Comment: @MartinRindarøy then put BatIntf in a separate jar referred by both Bar.jar and Foo.jar

Comment: @MartinRindarøy or use reflection to invoke the method

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow ensure that `Foo` loads `Bar` with a custom class loader, and so when `Bar` calls `classLoader.close()` it closes the custom class loader created in `Foo`, instead of the system class loader?

Comment: @MartinRindarøy yes: Bar.jar is the only jar of the class loader, so it should work just as well. I don't see why you would prefer Bar to close it though...